# Windows 7 VPN Server

Tags: windows-7, iphone, vpn, routing

I have a computer running Windows 7 (x64) connected to the Internet and accepting incoming connections (VPN Server).

I want to be able to route all my traffic from my iPhone (especially web traffic) though the VPN server when I use public wifi (which I often do). I want it to run like a SSH tunnel (which is already set up and works great when I can use PuTTY).

Unfortunately, when I connect to my computer from my iPhone it connects fine and I can use local resources (ie. RDP or other local only systems) but I can not browse the Internet or use anything that isn't just going to my computer.
I am aware that there is a switch that is labeled "Route all traffic" and I do not want it off that is not what I want. In essence when I go to "whatismyip.org" on my iPhone when I'm connected to my VPN I want to see the ip address of my computer.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the "only" thing you want is HTTP (Web pages and alike), and you want your Windows box be the receiving party to the web service, you need a HTTP proxy. One of the best and most widely deployed proxies out there is [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org), although you should spend a couple of hours reading the documentation.

Comment: Although that would work I want to route my traffic from my iPhone through my home computer

Comment: you said that, and for that purpose I suggested squid.

Comment: If you talk "routing" like in "IP routing": this wouldn't be possible with a smartphone because you don't have enough control over the carriers' net. If it were possible, the IP of the phone would be "seen" in the webservers logs, and not your computers'. So squid would accomplish exactly what you described.